# Как считать функцию из LineEdit в QT Creator, чтобы в дальнейшем рассчитать определенный интеграл?

Tags: массивы, qt, функции, qtcreator

Задание такое: есть LineEdit, в который вводится пользователем функция вида y = f(x). Проблема в считывании этой функции - при использовании ui->lineEdit->text() соответственно в переменную типа QString передается целая строка. Пробовала разбить эту строку на символы и занести в массив типа QString:

```
QString text = ui->lineEdit->text();
QString sym[text.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < text.size(); i++)
{
    sym[i] = text.at(i);
}
```

Но вопрос в том, что делать дальше? Как мне из массива с символами сделать функцию, где *y* будет выражаться через *x*? Возможно, есть какие-то другие способы это сделать, но в интернете ничего подобного не находила... Еще могу добавить, что в моем случае это не ООП.
Вопрос не в том, как найти интеграл непосредственно, а как найти значение функции при каком-либо значении *x*.

Comment: 1. строим абстрактное синтаксическое дерево (AST-дерево), 2. делаем обход дерева для вычисления значения функции

Comment: Хорошо, а есть ещё какие-нибудь другие варианты?